# passing json in stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am calling a stored procedure and it is giving a syntax error, I am unable to figure it out. Can anyone help?

```
    "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\"billToId\":137,\"shipToId\":137,\"loadingId\":137,\"loadingLocationId\":2,\"billToLocat' at line 1",
```

It is a JSON that I am passing as a string.

Here's the stored procedure:

```
drop procedure if exists createRequisition;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE createRequisition(p_reqBranchId INT,p_unloadingJson JSON,locationsString text,p_quantity FLOAT,
p_expectedDeliveryDate DATE,p_loadingDate DATE,p_refId VARCHAR(255),p_notes TEXT,p_createdBy VARCHAR(255),p_vehicleId INT, p_vehicleName VARCHAR(255),p_isWeb int,p_priority int,p_editId int)
BEGIN
-- call SP_TMS_CreateRequisition()
  declare lastReqCode int;
  declare d_ReqCode text;
  declare d_branchCode text;
  declare lastInsert INT;
  declare d_branchIdsStr text;
  START transaction;
    if(p_editId is null) then
        BEGIN
            SET d_branchCode = (select group_concat(freighterCode) from Freighters join Branches on freighterId = branchFreighterId where branchId = p_reqBranchId);
            SET d_branchIdsStr = (select group_concat(branchId) from Branches where branchFreighterId = (select branchFreighterId from Branches where branchId = p_reqBranchId) );
            SET lastReqCode = (SELECT if(max(CAST(substring(reqCode,5) AS UNSIGNED))>0,max(CAST(substring(reqCode,5) AS UNSIGNED)),0) FROM Requisitions where find_in_set(reqBranchId,d_branchIdsStr));
            set d_ReqCode = (select concat(d_branchCode,lastReqCode+1));

            INSERT INTO Requisitions(reqCode,reqBranchId,vehicleId,vehicleName,loadingUnloadingJson,quantity,originalQuantity,deliveryDate,loadingDate,referenceNumber,notes,createdAt,createdBy,updatedAt,reqIsWeb,priority)
            VALUES(d_ReqCode,p_reqBranchId,p_vehicleId, p_vehicleName,p_unloadingJson,p_quantity,p_quantity,p_expectedDeliveryDate,p_loadingDate,p_refId,p_notes,NOW(),p_createdBy,NOW(),p_isWeb,p_priority);

            set lastInsert = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
            set locationsString = replace(locationsString,'reqId',lastInsert);
            set @reqLocationInsert = concat('INSERT INTO RequisitionDetails (requisitionId,billToBranchId,shipToBranchId,loadingBranchId,loadingLocationId,billToLocationId,shipToLocationId,skuId,skuQuantity,skuWeight,requisitionJson) VALUES',locationsString);
            PREPARE stmt from @reqLocationInsert;
            EXECUTE stmt;

            select lastInsert as reqId;
        END;
    else 
        BEGIN
            UPDATE `Requisitions`
                SET
                `vehicleId` = p_vehicleId,
                `vehicleName` = p_vehicleName,
                `loadingDate` = loadingDate,
                `referenceNumber` = p_refId,
                `notes` = p_notes,
                `updatedAt` = now(),
                `updatedBy` = p_createdBy,
                `priority` = p_priority
                WHERE `reqId` = p_editId;

            DELETE from RequisitionDetails where requisitionId = p_editId;
            set @reqLocationInsert = concat('INSERT INTO RequisitionDetails (requisitionId,billToBranchId,shipToBranchId,loadingBranchId,loadingLocationId,billToLocationId,shipToLocationId,skuId,skuQuantity,skuWeight,requisitionJson) VALUES',locationsString);
            PREPARE stmt from @reqLocationInsert;
            EXECUTE stmt;

            select lastInsert as reqId;
        END;
    end if;
COMMIT;
END
```

And the parameters that I am passing is: 
 call createRequisition(5,null,'(reqId,137,137,137,2,2,2,493,{\"billToId\":137,\"shipToId\":137,\"loadingId\":137,\"loadingLocationId\":2,\"billToLocationId\":2,\"shipToLocationId\":2,\"skuId\":493,\"skuWeight\":30,\"loadingbranchName\":\"New Branch \",\"loadingCompanyName\":\"Teja & Teja Pvt. Ltd\",\"loadingErpCode\":\"WERT\",\"loadingShortName\":\"Kolkata\",\"loadingLongName\":\"West Bengal, India\",\"shipToCompanyName\":\"Teja & Teja Pvt. Ltd\",\"shipTobranchName\":\"New Branch \",\"shipToErpCode\":\"WERT\",\"shipToShortName\":\"Kolkata\",\"shipToLongName\":\"West Bengal, India\",\"billToBranchName\":\"New Branch \",\"billToCompanyName\":\"Teja & Teja Pvt. Ltd\",\"billToErpCode\":\"WERT\",\"billToShortName\":\"Kolkata\",\"billToLongName\":\"West Bengal, India\",\"skuQuantity\":10})',
            10,null,'2019-10-18',
            '111','Just Do It',
            '17',2,
            'Open Daala zzz',1,'HIGH',null)

Comment: Can you post the stored procedure and some example invocation?.

Comment: I have updated the question, pls find. @wchiquito

Comment: In principle, I cannot reproduce the error indicated, the error generated is `Incorrect integer value: 'HIGH' for column 'p_priority' at row 1` that has nothing to do with the JSON data type. I understand that the JSON (does not appear to be a valid JSON) passed to the stored procedure is received by `locationsString` parameter, which is `TEXT` type. I don't understand where you really use the JSON data type. Basically `locationsString` parameter correctly receives the text string, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d4b75b6be154c23a4076f382c69f538f).

Comment: @wchiquito I have changed it. But still getting error.

Comment: What has changed?. Can you update your question with the changes?.